# Can "so" and "very" be used together?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, so-vs-very

Is it correct to use *so* and *very* together in a single sentence? For example:

> You are so very funny.

Is it grammatically correct or not?

Comment: Another angle: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-so-very.aspx

Answer (score 12):

The modification of one adverb by another is frequently found in English and is perfectly grammatical. Here *so* reinforces *very*, itself an intensifier.

Comment: Just a note: I find expressions such as "so very funny" are hyperbolically humorous. This sounds as an tongue-in-cheek exaggeration, so I would use it only in these situations. OTOH, I am no English expert and my opinion may be wrong, but this seems to be the case to me nonetheless.

Comment: @brandizzi: It can be. It all depends on the context - and on the tone of voice in which it is said.

Comment: I'm sure it will make Brenda Holloway [so very happy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27ve_Made_Me_So_Very_Happy) to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

*So very* is used as intensifier of *very*, in negative, affirmative, and interrogative sentences, such as the following ones:

> You will forget **so very much** because you are overwhelmed at each stage.

> The end result is not **so very different** from that of the railway compartment.

> The input to filter w(n) is the sinusoidal sweep, **so very little** adjustment should be needed to get nearly perfect cancellation of the sinusoidal portion of the combined signal.

> What is **so very interesting** here is that the overwhelming majority reports being either extremely or very happy with that predictability.

The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* contains examples of phrases using *so very* that are distributed over different sections as in the following graph.

[image: screenshot]

Looking at the *Corpus of Historical American English*, I find the following sentences:

> Mary Erskine was **so very useful** at home, that a convenient time for sparing her never came.

> At one end of the room is a great fire-place, **so very spacious**, that there is room enough for three or four boys to stand in each of the chimney corners.

> They shone **so very brightly**.

The graph showing the usage of *so very* over time is the following one.

[image: screenshot]